# Case Condition with GroupBy in Linq for duplicate records

Tags: c#, linq, duplicates

I have a list of records where I need to filter the list for duplicate records and take only one record with **AddressType = "POST"**.

Let me show your the example:

```
class Test
{
public string Id {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
public string AddressType {get; set;}
}
```

This is the data I have:

```
var data = new List<Test>{
                new Test {Id = "1", Name = "Test11", AddressType = "POST" },
                new Test {Id = "1", Name = "Test12", AddressType = "STREET" },
                new Test {Id = "2", Name = "Test122", AddressType = "POST" },
                new Test {Id = "3", Name = "Test123", AddressType = "POST" },
                new Test {Id = "4", Name = "Test1", AddressType = "POST" },
                new Test {Id = "4", Name = "Test1", AddressType = "POST" },
                new Test {Id = "5", Name = "Test11", AddressType = null }
            };
```

I'm trying to remove the duplicate records based on Id and AdressType = "POST" with this query:

```
var filteredData = data.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

This removes the duplicacy but I want to take the record with AddressType = "POST" and the above query randomly picked the First record. I have tried another thing where with this query but it is not working:

```
var filteredData = data.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => x.First()).Where(x => x.AddressType == "POST").ToList();
```

Expected Output:

```
Test {Id = "1", Name = "Test11", AddressType = "POST" }, 
Test {Id = "2", Name = "Test122", AddressType = "POST" }, 
Test {Id = "3", Name = "Test123", AddressType = "POST" },
Test {Id = "4", Name = "Test1", AddressType = "POST" },
Test {Id = "5", Name = "Test11", AddressType = null }
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Update: Thanks to the solutions below, it worked but in case of any null value in the list. It breaks. So by adding FirstOrDefault() I'm able to handle the null error but the details of that row is not getting added to the result. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Could you add your expectation result please

Comment: @arslanaybars - I have added the expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting the predicate inside the call to `first`:

```
var filteredData = data
   .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
   .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AddressType == "POST"))
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks for the immediate reply. Just curious why it isn't working outside the First() method as I was specifying the same condtion. Any idea?

Comment: Yes, you were doing `.First()` before the `.Where()`. After you have done `.First()` you are no longer working on a list, but on an `Object` of some kind. It would have worked if you did `.Where()` before the `.First()`. `Select(x => x.Where(x => x.AddressType == "POST").First())`. Putting the predicate inside `first` is more elegant though :)

Comment: Ok great. Just one issue with the solution that in case of null value in AddressType, it is throwing exception. So I added 
var filteredData = data
   .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
   .Select(x => x.FirstorDefault(x => x.AddressType == "POST"))
   .ToList(); but I need the record in case of null as well. It is not fetching the details in case of null AddressType.

Comment: @SahilSharma Ah, sure, `FirstOrDefault` is a better fit in that case. Updated my answer to use that instead! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can group by your selected columns then select FirstOrDefault(). try bellow;

```
var list = data.GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.AddressType })
               .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AddressType == "POST" || a.AddressType == null))
               .Where(y => y != null)
               .ToList();
```

Same as your expected result:

```
   ID   Name     AddressType

    1   Test11   POST
    2   Test122  POST
    3   Test123  POST
    4   Test1    POST
    5   Test11   null
```

Hope the answer helps someone.

Comment: Yes thats also worked but I'm struck in case of AddressType as null. I need the Name and Id details for null as well but this condition is not getting me that details. Any solution?

Comment: if AddressType is null. do you want to add all null AddressType object ?

Comment: @SahilSharma can you add some dummy data to question. for your state

Comment: Yes with other details ID and Name

Comment: var data = new List<Test>{
                new Test {Id = "1", Name = "Test11", AddressType = "POST" },
                new Test {Id = "1", Name = "Test12", AddressType = "STREET" },
                new Test {Id = "2", Name = "Test122", AddressType = "POST" },
                new Test {Id = "3", Name = "Test123", AddressType = "POST" },
                new Test {Id = "4", Name = "Test1", AddressType = "POST" },
                new Test {Id = "4", Name = "Test1", AddressType = null }
            };

Comment: so as I understand you wanted if AddressType is null never add to list? right I am updating my answer

Comment: @SahilSharma you can add this '.Where(x => x.AddressType != null)' before group by

Comment: I have updated the question but I want to filter on the basis of "POST" but if there is null record, also add it to the list. Please see the updated question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157641/discussion-between-arslanaybars-and-sahil-sharma).